# Trigger Jenkins job on release GitHub Event

Tags: jenkins, github

I have created a jenkins job and I want it to be triggered when ever I create a new Release in my GitHub repo.

My job has the following configuration:
-Refspec: '+refs/tags/*':'refs/remotes/origin/tags/*'
-Branch specifier: **/tags/**

Now in my github repo I have created a trigger to run whenever a new Release is published, but this webhook does not seem to trigger my job, but if I switch this webhook to run after every push event, my job gets triggered multiple times, not just when I have published a new release.